# How to set real time input value to link through iFrame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please see below 2 HTML pages, I have 1 page inside iFrame call other page.
what I exactly need, I want in "iframe.html" you can see text field. when I write something in that input box, real time that value should take inside href=""

**Note :** iframe.html page is pure html page. I can't use jquery inside that page. I have to access that page from index.html page.

I have tried some jquery code, but only I wrote function.

this is index.html page.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="iframe.html" id="myframe"></iframe>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $($("#myframe").contents().find('body')).on("click", 'a[href="#editable-link"]', function(e) {

    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is "iframe.html" page.

```
<html>
<head>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter URL">
    <a href="" id="editable-link">Read More</a>
</body>
</html>
```

can anyone help me to resolve this problem. it will very helpful.
thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery/JavaScript: accessing contents of an iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)

Comment: Hi,
But still I am confuse how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#myframe').load(function(){
  $('#myframe').contents().find('input').bind('input',function(e) {
      var url = $('#myframe').contents().find('input').val();
      $('#myframe').contents().find('#editable-link').prop('href',url);
   });
});
```

Comment: Hi,
but how can I real time fill it when I write something in text field. I am stop in that point.

Comment: Hey buddy,
actually I need, when I put some URL inside input box. that URL should set as Read more link. in href=" "

Comment: It's working well buddy.
you are a great developer. unfortunately still I haven't 15 reputation to vote you. but I think some one will vote you. :)
cheers!

Comment: @pet4RX could you mark mine as the answer? I think you can do that without 15 rep. Thanks! (You can do that by clicking the check mark below the upvote/downvote arrows.)